# Media queries in Next JS

Tags: css, next.js, responsive

I've been trying and looking for some hours now and I couldn't find a solution for my issue.
I'm trying to use different files for my media query breakpoints in Next JS, and they seem to not do anything.

I created them in:
styles/queries/sizeone.css (the first breakpoint)

I imported them on my _app.tsx just like this, and also overwrited the viewport tag from default Next JS head.

```js
import { AppProps } from 'next/app';
import Head from 'next/head'

import '../styles/globals.css'
import '../styles/normalize.css'
import '../styles/queries/sizeone.css'

function App({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {  
  return (
    <>
    <Head>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    </Head>
    <Component {...pageProps} />
    </>
  )
}

export default App;
```

This is what I'm doing inside my sizeone.css file, it's just a simple media query.

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 1px) and (max-width: 767px){
  #hero .content .title h1 {
    text-align: center;
    color: var(--main-color);
    font-family: var(--main-font);
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: 0 0;
  }
}
```

This is how I'm applying styles to the elements:

```js
            <section id={styles.hero}>
                <div className="wrapper">
                    <div className={styles.content}>

                        <div className={styles.title}>
                            <h1>Creating <span className="gradient-text">remarkable</span> <br /><span className="gradient-text">experiences</span> through digital art.</h1>
                            <p>Freelancing UI/UX design & Front-end development</p>
```

This is the piece that is shown on the sizeone.css file.

Thank you for taking your time and reading my question, hope we can find a solution for this :)

Comment: Hi Gonçalo and welcome to StackOverflow. The example you've provided doesn't really show how you apply the styles to any of the tags/components. Please provide minimal reproducible example according to: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Hey! I just added how I'm actually applying styles to elements, hope it helps and is according to the minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, you're mixing up two ways of assigning CSS classes: the **standard way** and the **CSS modules way**. You might want to read more about this topic at: [CSS Tricks: CSS Modules](https://css-tricks.com/css-modules-part-1-need/)

An example speaks a thousand words, so please notice the difference in how I imported CSS files and how I applied classes in two examples below.

**1. Standard way**:

```css
/* globals.css */
.big {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```js
import '../styles/globals.css';
export default function App() {
  return <p className="big">Standard big</p>;
}
```

**2. CSS modules**:

```css
/* heading.module.css */
.big {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```js
import styles from './heading.module.css';
export default function Heading() {
  return <p className={styles.big}>CSS Modules big</p>;
}
```

---

CSS files imported in the `_app.js` file should be global to the entire application and you shouldn't use CSS modules here - use standard CSS.

Any other styles that are specific to a particular component should be imported in the respective component's JS/TS file and the preferred way of doing this in Next.js is using CSS modules.

Comment: Hey! Thank you a lot for taking time to actually explain this. I knew I was doing a mix of the global way and module way, would that be a problem? I only use the global way for small things, such us containers and buttons, etc... Kind of little components of the code. And to see if I understood your solution, to actually make a responsive file for each breakpoint, I should do import it inside each page, so I can actually work with the module CSS? Thank you a lot again.

Comment: The answear depends on how your app is structured. However, you should not mix up the "standard way" and CSS modules too often as it might become unbearable very quickly. As a rule of a thumb, stick to simple, general styles in the `_app.js` file - maybe even try to restrict yourself to using CSS tag selectors only, and avoid class selectors. Anything else, along with responsive design is best done in CSS modules.

Comment: Hmm, I understand what you mean, but I'm using the "standard way" only for global properties like I said, there isn't much in there. And then I use modules to separate pages and components, I don't know if I'm correct, but I saw that this is the best way to devide your code in parts. My question is, is it possible to do separated files for media queries like this?

Comment: Hello to everyone possible readers and moderators, I just fixed my issue with the advice that @83C10 gave me, I'm now using "standard css" as my main resource and modules for components. Thank you!

Comment: @GonçaloMedeiros Glad to hear that, you can accept this answer so that others know this helped you out.